# Pass CSV File as Parameter to Web Service

Tags: mongodb, csv, soaplib

How to pass **CSV file** contents as parameter to **web service** in python.Now i am passing only 5 values to web service and inserting it to mongodb database. I am using soaplib web service and mongodb database,using soaplib load data to database.
How to pass CSV file contents to web service and insert it to mongodb database?

Thanks

Comment: i just passed values through command prompt,but now i want to send csv file content as parameter to web service and in web service i am storing data in mongodb database.how to do that?

Comment: Which driver you are using to connect to MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following steps:

1. Firstly locate the CSV file location, which is programmatically
   accessible from your Python. Consider it as `path`
2. Go through this **[link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)**, read the file similar to the example
   quoted in the linked article.

   **Example:**

   ```
   fo = open(path + "yourfile.csv", "r+")
   str = fo.read(10);
   ```
3. Open Connection to MongoDB with your **[mongo-python-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver)**

   **Example:**

   ```
   import pymongo
   client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
   ```
4. Then ultimately pass the content of the file, which you read in step

   **Example**: `db.my_collection.save({"CSV_FileContent": Obj_CSV_File})`

### To pass your file content from your python program to a web service, you may try following:

- XML is ok, but not the best way at all (because if unnecessary metadata that is included in XML) [Large XML Data in Web Services](http://www.coderanch.com/t/224691/Web-Services/java/Design-Large-XML-Data-Web).
- [Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTOM) is the best to consider.